# Relocated Codeigniter website on my Server- now giving 403 Forbidden Error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am newbie in Web Development and have recently completed my web development course to build an MLM website for my business. Fortunately, I got source code of whole website developed by someone on Codeigniter MVC Framework. I installed source code on my server, connected to relevant database and everything was correctly. The website was running till yesterday and now suddenly it is giving me **`403 Forbidden Error`** displaying **`You don't have permission to access / on this server.`**

I am not at all familiar with Codeigniter and have no idea what should I do. But here I am posting some code, might be relevant for reference. Any help will be appreciable :/

Root Folder: `public_html/mlm`

**`.htaccess` File Code:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Please help me on this. I don't know what relevant file should I look for. If you  need other code I will add it in here.

Thank you.

Comment: Is there something written to your server's error log?

Comment: No sir no entry after 26 April 2018.

Comment: what url you accessing giving this error?

Comment: Sir the main page. index.php in root directory mlm

Comment: what is the location of your `.htaccess` file